# Unable to get location co-ordinates and display them on screen

Tags: android, android-location

My requirement is very simple.

I want to get the user's location and display the same on screen.

The emulator shows Currently reported location correctly. But I am unable to extract the same to my TextView. Not quite sure what is wrong here.

Please find my code below. Help appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.varun.weatherbee;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    TextView mLongitudeText;
    TextView mLatitudeText;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitutde;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLatitudeText);
        mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLongitudeText);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders();
        for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
            Log.i(TAG, providers.get(i));
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission Granted");
            return;
        }
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
            mLongitudeText.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 1000, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to update the textviews in onLocationChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

1.your runtime `permission` check is wrong

2.Also `getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` can return null [See here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String))

3.You can change `textview` with updated location in `onLocationChanged()` method

here is a simple example:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    TextView mLongitudeText;
    TextView mLatitudeText;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitutde;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLatitudeText);
        mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLongitudeText);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders();
        for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
            Log.i(TAG, providers.get(i));
        }


        //location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (isLocationPermissionGranted()) {
            location = getLastKnownLocation();
            if (location != null) {
                mLatitudeText.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
                mLongitudeText.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
            }
        }
    }


    private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (isLocationPermissionGranted())
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 1000, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitudeText.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
        mLongitudeText.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public boolean isLocationPermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission: " + permissions[0] + "was " + grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes my getLastKnownLocation was indeed returning null. You example helped a lot! Thank You!

Comment: If the answer works ..mark it as correct for future references...thankx